# 17.04 crashes on Gnome startup

Tags: boot, 17.04

I have installed the 17.04 upgrade from 16.10. It continually crashes on Gnome desktop but will run on Unity - but a lot of things don't work on this. Do I need to do a new fresh install (I am reluctant to do this as there are things on y hard drive I would like to save)? Or is there a fix??

Comment: If all we know is that it crashes its unlikely we can help. What does it actually say, what kind of machine are you running, how did you upgrade... Those are juste a few examples of what could actually help us understand what went wrong.

Comment: I use an HP elite book8440p with 8Gb RAM 64bit 2.4Ghz x4 processor.

Comment: It was upgraded from Ubuntu website - worked fine with 16.10 but now just boots up and will run for a couple of minutes before going black and then back to log in page.  Also crashes if I go into a programme .It will boot up on Unity desktop but with limited functionality

Comment: What do you mean Ubuntu website? You downloaded  a new ISO and overwrote your current install?

Comment: Yes, a new iso - i386 as suggested as an update from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Was your Ubuntu already a 32-bit install ? And how did you install the update, booted to the ISO or mounted it on your running Ubuntu ?

Comment: I was using 64 bit 16.10. New install by mounting it on running Ubuntu

Comment: ... You've upgraded a 64-bit OS with a 32-bit upgrade. How Ubuntu even let you do that I do not know but you've effectively messed up your system so badly I don't really see a more time effective solution than reinstalling. Note that you can reinstall without erasing your /home to keep your personal files.

Comment: For future reference, you can update Ubuntu from the Software application instead of downloading ISOs, you have far fewer chances of messing up your system.

Comment: Thanks - I think that a re install is the best way to go.